# Getting previous index values for the given string

Tags: ios, indexing, loading

Here is my problem. I had an uipickerview component in which it contains data, I want index values that are above the selected value. Here is the example below.

proj1
proj2
proj3
holidays
sickleave
proje4
--select--
proj5
proj6
proj7
proj8

```
-(void)Benefits
{

    NSString *Benefitpost =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"username=%@",[self.projectpicker dataSource]];

    NSString *Benefiturl = @"http:picker.com/GetBenefitTypes";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:Benefiturl];

    NSData *BenefitpostData = [Benefitpost dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];




    NSString *BenefitpostLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[BenefitpostData length]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *Benefitrequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [Benefitrequest setURL:url];
    [Benefitrequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [Benefitrequest setValue:BenefitpostLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [Benefitrequest setValue:@"application/projectpicker" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [Benefitrequest setValue:@"application/jsonArray" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [Benefitrequest setHTTPBody:BenefitpostData];


    NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];
    NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
    NSData *BenefiturlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:Benefitrequest returningResponse:&response error:&error];
    NSURLRequest *BenefiturlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                                cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad
                                            timeoutInterval:30];


    // Make synchronous request
    BenefiturlData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:BenefiturlRequest
                                    returningResponse:&response
                                                error:&error];
    if ([response statusCode] >= 200 && [response statusCode] < 300)
    {
        NSString *BenefitresponseData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:BenefiturlData
                                                                 options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];

        NSArray *Benefitentries = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[BenefitresponseData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                                           options:0 error:&error];
        if(!Benefitentries)
        {
            NSLog(@"Error : %@", error);
        }
        else{

            for (NSDictionary *Benefitentry in Benefitentries) {
                benID = [Benefitentries valueForKey:@"ID_LEAVES"];
                BenefitNames = [Benefitentries valueForKey:@"NM_LEAVES"];

            }
            NSLog(@"BenefitNames : %@", BenefitNames);
            _projectpicker.delegate = self;
            _projectpicker.dataSource = self;
            [self loadprojects];
        }

    }       else {

    }
}
    -(void)loadprojects
    {

        NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"username=%@",[self.projectpicker dataSource]];
        //NSString *pickername = [self.projectpicker dataSource];
        //NSString *key = @"Da9s^a2Rp4na6R$ikiAsav3Is@niWsa";

        //NSString *encrypteduname = [AESCrypt encrypt:pickername password:key];

        // Code for Project loading

        NSString *projecturltemp = @"http://picker.com/GetAssignedProjects";
        NSString *str = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"UserLoginIdSession"];
        NSString *usrid = str;
        NSString * projecturl =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",projecturltemp,usrid];


        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:projecturl];

        NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];




        NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postData length]];
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
        [request setURL:url];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
        [request setValue:@"application/projectpicker" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
        [request setValue:@"application/jsonArray" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [request setHTTPBody:postData];


        NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];
        NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
        NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
        NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                                    cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad
                                                timeoutInterval:30];


        // Make synchronous request
        urlData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest
                                        returningResponse:&response
                                                    error:&error];
        if ([response statusCode] >= 200 && [response statusCode] < 300)
        {

            NSString *responseData =[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:urlData
                                                                    options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];
            NSArray *entries = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[responseData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                                               options:0 error:&error];
            if(!entries)
            {
                NSLog(@"Error : %@", error);
            }
            else{

                for (NSDictionary *entry in entries) {
                    projID = [entries valueForKey:@"ID_PROJECT"];
                    projectNames = [entries valueForKey:@"NM_PROJECT"];
                }
                randomSelection=[BenefitNames arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:projectNames];
                randomSelectionID = [benID arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:projID];
                _projectpicker.delegate = self;
                _projectpicker.dataSource = self;
            }

        }       else {

        }
    }


-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    int numberofRows = 0;
    switch (component) {

        case 0:
            numberofRows = [randomSelection count];
            [pickerView reloadComponent:1];
            break;
        case 1:
            numberofRows = [taskNames count];
            [pickerView reloadComponent:2];
            break;
        case 2:
            numberofRows = [subtaskNames count];
            break;
    }
    return numberofRows;
}
-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    NSString *title;
    if(component == 0) {
            [pickerView reloadComponent:1];
            [pickerView reloadComponent:2];
        //[randomSelection addObjectsFromArray:projectNames];        
        title = [randomSelection objectAtIndex:row];
    }
    else if (component == 1){
            [pickerView reloadComponent:2];
            title = [taskNames objectAtIndex:row];
    }
    else{
            title = [subtaskNames objectAtIndex:row];

    }
    return title;

}

-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    //NSLog(@"%@",myArrayString);
    //NSLog(@"%@",myTaskArrayString);
    if(component == 0){
    NSNumber *myProjectArrayString = [randomSelectionID objectAtIndex:row];
    lblProjects.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",myProjectArrayString];
    lblProjects.hidden = YES;
        NSLog(@"Selected Color: %@. Index of selected color: %i", [randomSelection objectAtIndex:row], row);
        //[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", row];
    hdnlblProjects.text = [randomSelection objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]];
    [self loadtasks];
    [pickerView reloadComponent:1];
    [pickerView reloadComponent:2];
    }
    //lblProjects.hidden = YES;
    else if(component == 1)
    {
    NSNumber *myTaskArrayString = [taskID objectAtIndex:row];
    lblTasks.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",myTaskArrayString];
        lblTasks.hidden = YES;
        hdnlblTasks.text = [taskNames objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:1]];
    [self loadsubtasks];
    [pickerView reloadComponent:2];
    }
    else if(component == 2)
    {
        NSNumber *mysubtaskArrayString = [subtskID objectAtIndex:row];
        lblSubTasks.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",mysubtaskArrayString];
        lblSubTasks.hidden = YES;
        hdnlblSubTasks.text = [subtaskNames objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:2]];
    //lblTasks.text = [taskNames objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:1]];
    //lblTasks.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", myTaskArrayString];
    //lblSubTasks.text = [subtaskNames objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:2]];
    }
}
```

So when any user selects "--select--", i want to get the index position of the --select--. How to get the position? As proj1,2,3.. are generated dynamically so cant use or fix it with a static value.Please help me out in this..

Comment: is total data comes from single array? if yes will --select-- will be constant(i mean text doesn't change index may change)

Comment: No It comes from webservice and position of the select may change depending on inserted values

Comment: And Yes Text will not change and index may change..

Comment: can you paste you array information so that i can your array and give you an answer exactly

Comment: Sure I will edit the Post and past it

Comment: Resut for NSLOg is : projID : (
    "Benefit Types",
    Vacation,
    Sick,
    "Comp.day",
    "Pers.holidays",
    Overtime,
    "Jury Duty",
    Bereavement,
    "Fest holidays",
    Holidays,
    "new test",
    "New Leave 1",
    "New Leave 2",
    "--Select--",
    "DL",
    "Forms",
    "ES ",
    CS,
    "New Project",
    "BTS-Panasonic Project1",
    "BTS-Panasonic  Stereo",
    "Soma  Project1",
    "Project 001",
    "test project 1",
    "LG Project 1"
)